# Calling std::remove_if on list whose value_type is moveable but not copyable

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I am trying something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
 explicit MyClass(int) {...};
 MyClass(MyClass&& that) { swap(that); }
private:
 MyClass(const MyClass&); // disabled, pre-C++11 syntax
 MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&); // disabled, pre-C++11 syntax
};
```

Now I have a list of these where I insert them through emplace and I am trying to do something like this.

```
std::list<MyClass> lst;
std::remove_if(lst.begin(), lst.end(), [&,this](MyClass& mcl) { return mcl.is_foo();});
```

On gcc 4.6.x, I keep getting this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63:0,
             from simple_file_cache.cpp:5:
file_cache_entry.h: In function ‘_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate)   
[with_FIter = std::_List_iterator<MyClass>, _Predicate = 
AnotherClass::foo_bar(std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int>)::<lambda(MyClass&)>]’:
anotherclass.cpp:225:11:   instantiated from here
anotherclass.h:68:18: error: ‘MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass&)’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:1149:13: error: within this context
make: *** [simple_file_cache.o] Error 1
```

Why is it looking for a copy constructor?

Comment: `std::remove` or `std::remove_if`? Your title and your code doesn't match.

Comment: Also note that the C++11 support in GCC 4.6 is severely limited.

Comment: Actually, `std::remove_if` on a `std::list` doesn't make such sense to me. I'd rather use `std::list::erase` or `std::list::remove_if`.

Comment: *"Why is it looking for a copy constructor?"* It is not. It's looking for an assignment function.

Comment: Fixed the typo: remove -> remove_if.

Comment: @dyp, do you mean if you intended to just move a set of matching elements to the end of a list, you'd not use std::remove_if. list::erase and list::remove_if would delete elements - something I don't want.

Comment: I'm not sure `remove_if` guarantees that the elements will truly be moved to the end of the list, nor do I think it guarantees the order of those elements. I'll look it up.

Comment: From the C++ Standard (draft), [alg.remove]/6 about `remove_if`: "*Note:* each element in the range `[ret,last)`, where `ret` is the returned value, has a valid but unspecified state, because the algorithms can eliminate elements by moving from elements that were originally in that range."

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to define a move *assignment-operator* for `remove_if`. It's not declared implicitly if there's a user-declared copy assignment-operator (or a user-declared copy ctor, or dtor, or ...).

The following seems to compile under g++4.6:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

class MyClass
{
public:
 explicit MyClass(int) {};
 MyClass(MyClass&&) {}
 MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) {return *this;}
private:
 MyClass(const MyClass&); // disabled, pre-C++11 syntax
 MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&); // disabled, pre-C++11 syntax
};

int main()
{
    std::list<MyClass> lst;

    // compiles, but why use that:
    //std::remove_if(lst.begin(), lst.end(), [](MyClass& mcl) { return true; });

    // also compiles, makes more sense to me (but that depends on the context):
    lst.remove_if([](MyClass& mcl) { return true; });
}
```

Note you should consider making both move functions `noexcept`, if you can guarantee that.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb01004c52f8b29d)

---

If you want to move some elements of the list to the end of the list, I'd rather use an algorithm based on `splice`. For example,

```
template<class value_type, class allocator, class F>
//typename std::list<value_type, allocator>::iterator
void
move_to_end_if(std::list<value_type, allocator>& list, F condition)
{
    if(list.size() < 2) return; //list.end();

    auto const former_last = std::prev(list.end());

    for(auto i = list.begin(); true; ++i)
    {
        if(condition(*i))
        {
            list.splice(list.end(), list, i);
        }

        if(i == former_last) break;
    }

    // return ????;
}
```

This moves all elements satisfying the condition to the actual (current) end of the list, preserving their relative order.

*Note: The algorithm should return an iterator to the end of the non-moved sequence, or `list::end()`. Haven't found an elegant way yet to do that.*

Comment: Of course, you'll need to implement those functions ;)

Comment: Maybe it's possible to generalize this algorithm. I tried using an additional "target" iterator (`move_to_if`), but I'm not sure if the `end` iterator is invalidated by `splice`.

Comment: [`move_to_end_if` should probably be called `stable_list_partition` (with the opposite sense for the predicate).](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9992ebafebc4c72) I agree it should return the partition point to be consistent with [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition). It's nice that `stable_list_partition` performs O(N) splices for a list of N items without `std::stable_partition`'s requirement of additional storage to get that complexity guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

@dyp's post already addresses the OP's situation.

But for anyone else who came here trying to determine whether `remove_if` will copy or move the values:

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of copy assignment (until C++11)move assignment (since C++11)) ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove))

In case youre using C++ 11 or newer, and vector values have only the copy assignment defined, `remove_if` will resort to using the copy assignment. I verified this locally, but didn't find documentation online.